# Problema con puerto node.js y CentOS 6

Tags: nodejs, ubuntu, socket, puertos, firewall

Amigos tengo días buscando y aun no encuentro nada, tengo mi aplicación node.js corriendo en un servidor CentOS 6. Estoy usando las librerias socket.io y express... Desde la consola puedo ver que el servidor node apertura el puerto de escucha sin problemas pero al intentar acceder desde el navegador como cliente. La conexión falla, tarda demasiado en responder. Ya instale antes este mismo sistema en otros servidores y me ha funcionado sin problemas, he llegado a pensar que el problema son los puertos o el firewall, que creen que ustedes? que puedo hacer?

El servidor es un VPS no tiene nada instalado, todo lo he instalado yo. No he instalado firewall's

Aca les dejo algunas capturas de pantalla con el problema:

[image: Mensaje en consola, indicando que ha iniciado la app node y apertura del puerto 8085]

[image: Error en el navegador]

El puerto que estoy utilizando es el 8085, como pueden ver desde la consola se inicia correctamente, pero al intentar acceder desde el navegador no responde. Tienen idea de que puede estar ocurriendo?

Gracias.

Comment: por favor proporciona un [mcve]

Comment: Gracias fedorqui, he aprendido un poco más de stackoverflow, no sabia lo del  Ejemplo mínimo, completo y verificable. Espero que ahora se entienda un poco mas mi problema.

Comment: ¿ En que interfaz de red estás escuchando ? No serias el primero que se olvida de cambiar `localhost` o `127.0.0.1` y poner `0.0.0.0`.